# Why doesn't BlackBerry let me click on this link?

Tags: html, email, blackberry

This is a link in an HTML email.. Other links in this email work, but this one does not get recognized in a BlackBerry as a link, so you can't click on it.  Does anyone know why that might be?  Here's the markup for it:

```
<a title="Continue" 
   style="display: block; width:200px; border:1px solid #336699; text-align: center; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif; color:#336699; font-weight:bold; text-decoration: none;" 
    href="https://www.mydomain.com/mypage.aspx?id=8430650">Continue ››</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has something to do with the style attribute- perhaps it's too complex or there is a particular style or combination of styles causing this... would take too much time to try every different combination, so we're moving on to plan B.

Thank you for your suggestions all!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its the way the html is being parsed. I wonder if the "> >" after the text Continue are throwing off the parser.
You should try and send yourself an e-mail without the "> >". You might have found a bug.

Either that or maybe remove the style and see if that works.

I don't own a blackberry so I'm just giving suggestions. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `>` characters as `&gt;` otherwise it may confuse the HTML parser thinking they are HTML element closing characters.

Comment: They are actually not &gt symbols, they are something else... still, they are pretty unusual.. let me try it with more straightforward &gt instead.